# can we Reload UIView?

Tags: iphone

HI all,

is there any way round,in which we can reload UIView,like we do in table view, reloadtable?

is it possible?

regards
shishir

Answer (score 3):

Call `-setNeedsDisplay`.

```
[myView setNeedsDisplay]; // will cause the view to redraw itself on the next draw cycle.
```

Comment: what i was trying to do is,
i hv five tabs,
first tabs contains 4 custom button, having differnt images on each button.

my another tab shows few language, when i selct wone of the language from table view, whole application gets converted according to languague sleected.
But when move to my first tab, it still remains the same.
when i close my app and open again, that first tab's view which contains 4 buttons ,gets changed this time.

i don knw what is going wrong.

after closing my app, that view is changed, but on instance it is not changing

Comment: *sigh* - This is the kind of information you should have provided in your original question. "How to refresh a UIView" has nothing to do with your actual problem.

I suggest you read the documentation for something like NSNotification and use them to inform your views that the language has change, and then refresh the views that way.